# EncodingGroovyMethods and decodeBase64

Tags: groovy

I have ran into an issue on Windows where encoded file is read and decoded using `EncodingGroovyMethods#decodeBase64`:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream('/endoded_file').text.decodeBase64()
```

This gives me:

> bad character in base64 value

File itself has CRLF endings and groovy decodeBase64 implementation snippet has a comment so:

```
            } else if (sixBit == 66) {
                // RFC 2045 says that I'm allowed to take the presence of
                // these characters as evidence of data corruption
                // So I will
                throw new RuntimeException("bad character in base64 value"); // TODO: change this exception type
            }
```

I looked up RFC 2045 and CLRF pair is suppose to be legal. I have tried same with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64#decodeBase64` and it works. Is this a bug in groovy or was this intentional ?

I am using groovy 2.4.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a different way of how corrupt data is handled. Looking at the source code of Base64 in Apache commons, you can see the documentation:

```
 * Ignores all non-base64 characters. This is how chunked (e.g. 76 character) data is handled, since CR and LF are
 * silently ignored, but has implications for other bytes, too. This method subscribes to the garbage-in,
 * garbage-out philosophy: it will not check the provided data for validity.
```

So, while the Apache Base64 decoder silently ignores the corrupt data, the Groovy one will complain about it.  The RFC documentation is a bit fuzzy about it:

```
   In base64 data, characters other than those in Table 1, line breaks, and other
   white space probably indicate a transmission error, about which a
   warning message or even a message rejection might be appropriate
   under some circumstances.
```

While warning messages are hardly useful (who checks for warnings anyway?), the Groovy authors decided to go into the path of 'message rejection'.

TLDR; they are both fine, just a different way of handling corrupt data. If you can, try to fix or reject the incorrect data.